# Using eli5 Permutation Importance in 32x32 images

Tags: python, keras, permutation

I´ve generated a keras model`(python) from my training 32x32 images dataset. Now, I create a numpy dataX with 100 validation images:

```
print(dataX.shape)
(100, 32, 32, 1)
```

So, we can notice that there are 100 images from size 32x32 and 1 channel.
When I run the following code:

```
predictions = model.predict(dataX)
y_pred=predictions.argmax(axis=1).astype(int)
```

The result is a (100,) shape y_pred: my model is working and dataX has the correct shape.

So, I want to use python eli5's PermutationImportance in dataX data. Something like this:

```
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state = 1).fit(dataX, y_true)
```

(y_true are the true labels for dataX)
But I have a problem, since it seems PermutationImportance is expecting a (100,number of features) data (and not 100,32,32,1 ). Maybe a (100,1024) matrix.

So i tried to create a class which could transform data shape before fit, predict. Something like this (considering image_size=32):

```
class Model_PI:
    def __init__(self, model):
          self.model=model

    def predict(self,X,y):
        X_=X.reshape(X.shape[0],image_size,image_size,1)
        return self.model.predict(X_,y)

    def fit(self,X,y):
        X_=X.reshape(X.shape[0],image_size,image_size,1)
        return self.model.fit(X_,y)

    def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
        return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X,y), sample_weight=sample_weight)

my_model=Model_PI(model)
```

and I used my_model instead of model. But when I try

```
perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state = 1).fit(dX, y_pred)
```

I got the following error message :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-2095af31af97> in <module>
----> 1 perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state = 1).fit(dX, y_pred)

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    200             si = self._cv_scores_importances(X, y, groups=groups, **fit_params)
    201         else:
--> 202             si = self._non_cv_scores_importances(X, y)
    203         scores, results = si
    204         self.scores_ = np.array(scores)

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py in _non_cv_scores_importances(self, X, y)
    224     def _non_cv_scores_importances(self, X, y):
    225         score_func = partial(self.scorer_, self.wrapped_estimator_)
--> 226         base_score, importances = self._get_score_importances(score_func, X, y)
    227         return [base_score] * len(importances), importances
    228 

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py in _get_score_importances(self, score_func, X, y)
    229     def _get_score_importances(self, score_func, X, y):
    230         return get_score_importances(score_func, X, y, n_iter=self.n_iter,
--> 231                                      random_state=self.rng_)
    232 
    233     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eli5/permutation_importance.py in get_score_importances(score_func, X, y, n_iter, columns_to_shuffle, random_state)
     84     """
     85     rng = check_random_state(random_state)
---> 86     base_score = score_func(X, y)
     87     scores_decreases = []
     88     for i in range(n_iter):

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
    369 def _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs):
    370     """Function that wraps estimator.score"""
--> 371     return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
    372 
    373 

<ipython-input-69-eeb6ee36656d> in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
     13     def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
     14         from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
---> 15         return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X,y), sample_weight=sample_weight)
     16 
     17 my_model=Model_PI(model)

<ipython-input-69-eeb6ee36656d> in predict(self, X, y)
      5     def predict(self,X,y):
      6         X_=X.reshape(X.shape[0],image_size,image_size,1)
----> 7         return self.model.predict(X_,y)
      8 
      9     def fit(self,X,y):

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1167                                             batch_size=batch_size,
   1168                                             verbose=verbose,
-> 1169                                             steps=steps)
   1170 
   1171     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    280         # Sample-based predictions.
    281         outs = []
--> 282         batches = make_batches(num_samples, batch_size)
    283         index_array = np.arange(num_samples)
    284         for batch_index, (batch_start, batch_end) in enumerate(batches):

~/anaconda3/envs/explicabilidade/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in make_batches(size, batch_size)
    369     num_batches = (size + batch_size - 1) // batch_size  # round up
    370     return [(i * batch_size, min(size, (i + 1) * batch_size))
--> 371             for i in range(num_batches)]
    372 
    373 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

BTW, i´ve created score method because it was an error when I was trying to run the above code. But now I am stuck. 
Any idea ?  or, is there a better way to make PermitationImportance workout with images (100,32,32,1 size data instead of 100,1024)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling model.predict with two arguments? You only need to feed the input to predict.

Comment: Sure ! You are right. no need to use X,y.

Comment: By any chance do anyone have an idea whether we can use GPU while using eli5 Permutation Importance.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, here is the class code which works just fine:

```
class Model_PI:
    def __init__(self, model,X):
        self.model=model

    def predict(self,X):
        X_=X.reshape(X.shape[0],image_size,image_size,1)
        return self.model.predict(X_).argmax(axis=1).astype(int)

    def fit(self,X,y):
        X_=X.reshape(X.shape[0],image_size,image_size,1)
        return self.model.fit(X_,y)

    def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        result=(y==self.predict(X)).sum()/y.shape[0]
        return result


my_model=Model_PI(model,dataX)
```

Thanks all